# "Partial" icon in a comparison table

Tags: tables, icons, symbols, comparison

I'm making a table comparing the features in different offerings, using checkmarks and blank spaces to denote whether a feature is available or not. There are a few edge cases where there's partial support of a feature in one of the offerings. I'm planning to use a symbol as well as a one-word description (e.g. "Partial") in the table, with a tooltip explaining the feature shown on hover or finger tap.

What would be the most fitting symbol for this partial state?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would drop the icon and go with just the "Partial" text.

I would also make this a clickable link (visually al least), so it is more obvious that you can find out more information (rather than having to hover).

However, if I had to choose an icon I would go with some kind of "half filled" shape. Perhaps a square or circle depending on the rest of your design style.

Very quick example (excuse the rough edges):

[image]